# How to Get An Array to Ignore Non numbers and Set it to 1 number per line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an array sort number program where the user enters an array of numbers and clicking the Sort button will sort the numbers into numerical numbers. What I am wondering is how to get my program to ignore non-numbers? And how to set it to 1 number each line instead of putting them all on the same line?

```js
var myarr = []; 

function addTo() { 
    myarr.push(document.getElementById("userinput").value); 
   
    console.log(myarr); //to confirm it has been added to the array    
}; 
 
function sortNumbers() {
    myarr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    document.getElementById("userinput").append = myarr;
      console.log(myarr);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userinput" /> 
<input type ="button" onclick="addTo()" value="Add Number" /> 
<button onclick="sortNumbers()">Sort</button>
```

Comment: It already ignores non-numbers by virtue of the `type=number` input attribute.  By "putting them all on the same line" did you mean when you do `console.log()`?  (This is trivial: `console.log(myarr.join('\n'))`)

Comment: by 1 number, do you mean 1 character or entire number?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```js
var myarr = []; 

function addTo() { 
    let n =document.getElementById("userinput").value; 
    myarr.push(n);
    document.getElementById("inputA").innerText = myarr.toString();
}; 
 
function sortNumbers() {
    myarr.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
    ;
    let sortedB = document.getElementById("sortedB");
    document.getElementById("sorted").innerText = myarr.toString();
    sortedB.innerHTML = "";
    myarr.forEach(n => sortedB.innerHTML += "<br/>" + n);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userinput" /> 
<input type ="button" onclick="addTo()" value="Add Number" /> 
<button onclick="sortNumbers()">Sort</button>
<p>Input array: <span id="inputA"></span></p>
<p>Sorted on one line: <span id="sorted"></span>
  <br/>
  Sorted on different lines: <span id="sortedB"></span>
</p>
```